# Sikuli with Selenium Grid integration

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, sikuli

I have integrated Sikuli with Selenium web driver and it works fine on my local machine. Now I want to execute same scripts in remote machines. my scripts are usually sikuli based i.e. there is hardly any web automation. the whole project is for automating desktop application running on different remote machines.

think of POS Systems running on retail store.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know that sikuli is an image based automation which finds elements by checking the base image against the current visible screen.So to put it simply, it works where the code executes.So it is not possible on Grid as execution happens on Remote machine

There is already a [post somewhat answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019369/integrate-selenium-grid-and-sikuli-api) on that.That guy had written a blog on [Autoit,Sikuli and Other Tools with Selenium Grid](https://autumnator.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/autoit-sikuli-and-other-tools-with-selenium-grid/)

Also Go through this [LaunchPad Discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/139817)

And found this [sikuli remote control](https://github.com/enix12enix/sikuli-remote-control) to be interesting. I haven't used it But you can try it

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the images in the remote machine then it might work. Using Jenkins you can download the images to remote machine and selenium jenkins plugin to start execution. Just an idea, never tested.