# Sikuli - Selenium -Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid, sikuli, sikuli-script

Background: I have my sikuli-integrated selenium script on a Windows machine, and my test cases are running on a Mac (iPad Simulator). This Mac also has an appium server running on port 4723.

I want to use sikuli to click a button on the iPad Simulator. But this  does not work.

```
/* Is there a constructor that accepts an IP argument? Like
Screen s1 = new Screen("ip of mac"); ?*/

Screen s = new Screen();  
s.find(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.seprator+"playbutton.png"); 
s.click(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.seprator+"playbutton.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the .png files available on the target device (i.e. your ipad). I've done this when running distributed tests over multiple windows pcs by storing the files and having a method to copy files to the local device in my "before" step.

Comment: Ok , but how do i get the ipad screen in sikuli because Screen s = new Screen(); gives me the screen of the device in which code is being executed

Comment: I think this is a webdriver limitation, have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590691/sikuli-with-selenium-grid-integration